# Save print and hash output separately

Tags: linux, awk

New to the awk and linux environment

```
Store    Sales    ID     
X        500      A1
X        600      A1
Y        200      A2
Z        300      A3
...
```

I have a csv file which I am reading $2 column of and saving to a file 'book.csv'. At the same time I am creating a hash file of column $3 and saving it as 'ID.csv'. How can I do that in the same command? Basically combine these two into one.

```
awk -F '{ print $2 }' raw.csv > book.csv

awk -F '{a[$3]}END{for (x in a) print x}' raw.csv > ID.csv
```

Comment: When you say `creating a hash file of column $3` you actually just mean `creating a list of the unique values from column $3`, right? Or do you really want to call some tool to generate hash values from $3?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
$ awk '{print $2 > "book.csv"} !seen[$3]++{print $3 > "ID.csv"}' raw.csv

$ cat book.csv 
Sales
500
600
200
300

$ cat ID.csv 
ID
A1
A2
A3
```

Note that the use of `>` doesn't mean that the file will get overwritten everytime. That happens only once if the file already existed prior to executing the awk command. Use `>>` if you wish to append to already existing files.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamically save files based on column name

```sh
for i in 2 3; do
  column_name=$(cat raw.csv | awk "{print \$$i}" | head -n 1)
  cat raw.csv | awk "{print \$$i}" | tee $column_name.csv
done
```

Creates `Sales.csv` (column 2) `ID.csv`(column 3)

---

**Edit**: Answer given above is a bit redundant. Refer to comments below

---

Comment: this might be a good example of bad practices.

Comment: oh no!! can you elaborate

Comment: loop is not required, both `cat`s are not required, `head` is not required, also `tee` is useless. Escaping `$` in double quotes not required.  Can't really say anything right.

Comment: Your code can be written as `awk 'NR==1{split($0,cn)} {for(i=2;i<=3;i++) print $i > (cn[i]".csv")}' input_file`

Comment: ahhhh thats awesome - thank you!!!